# select data from mysql using php when id is empty

Tags: php, mysql

i get user member id if user is login. so i print user id . this worked so if user not login i print `0` for user id. now when i select any data form mysql ( ***if user not login $id = '0';***) my code not worked and i can't print result. i think my problem is single quotes in `id = '.$id.'` . how to fix this ?

checked if user login :

```
if($_SESSION['login'] > 0){
   $id = $row['id']} else {
   $id = '0';}
```

select data with user id :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM data_test WHERE id = '.$id.' AND productid = '.$row2['id'];

 ......
```

EDIT NOTE : `$row2['id']` is another result and Not relevant with `$id`.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you not just remove the quotes? I.E. `$id = 0;`?

Comment: where do you get `$row2`

Comment: Try without using . as id='$id',also where $row2?

Comment: @christian.thomas: +1. worked now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all PDO(or any prepared statement mechanism) would solve most of your problems in building queries. Such spaghetti SQL is not nice in reading.

Here you have examples: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Maybe you want to get records with empty value?
NULLs are treated in mysql little different way.
You have to do:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data_test WHERE id = '$id' AND productid = '{$row2['id']}'";
```

also should
    $row2['id']
be
    $row['id']